# Where do I file bugs for JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder

Now that [JavaFX Jira Issue Tracker](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/) has been moved to [JDK Bug System](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/secure/Dashboard.jspa), I don't find an option to file a new bug to the developers.

Rather, I find an information saying:

> Everyone with OpenJDK Author status or above has a JBS account which may be used to create and edit bugs. Those without accounts can view bugs anonymously.

As expected, to get a OpenJDK Author status you have a [huge list](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/#project-author) of formalities that you need to complete.

I have never used `JDK Bug System` before, but it is rather irritating, compared to the earlier `JavaFX Jira Issue Tracker`, where one could just sign up and create bug reports.

I have been to the [Report a Bug or Request a Feature](http://bugreport.java.com/) page and it just adds to my irritation.

Does this mean that I can **no longer submit** bugs for JavaFX, unless I use the `Report a Bug` page or am I **missing something** here?

Comment: yeah, now we are back to being mere mortals like the rest of java users ;-)

Comment: This is not a programming question but a product support question.

Comment: The product is an integral tool used only in software development, as described in the description of a good question on SO ...

Comment: I wish question about products that are software libraries for programmers to use and that have a single definitive answer were on-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @kleopatra If you have an OpenJDK JBS account, you can file bugs in the *special* OpenJDK bug reporting area; otherwise, you'll have to use https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/ like the answer suggested.

Comment: @TheTechExpertGuy yeah, sure - why are you telling me this (I'm a committer to openjfx, so should know <g>) You are aware that there had been massive changes to fx bug reporting, aren't you? In-the-beginning javafx had its own issue tracker where everybody (don't remember the hurdles, but certainly no author status required) could directly file. Then the fx issuetracker was merged into jdk tracker and with it the restriction to either use the web form or have have at least author status for direct writing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [OpenJFX project](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx) readme:

> If you think you have found a bug in OpenJFX, first make sure that you are testing against the latest version - your issue may already have been fixed. If not, search our [issues list](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/) in the Java Bug System (JBS) in case a similar issue has already been opened. More information on where and how to report a bug can be found at [bugreport.java.com](https://bugreport.java.com/).

For further reference: https://www.mail-archive.com/openjfx-dev@openjdk.java.net/msg09098.html

Comment: My bad that I didn't mention it in the question, but I have already been to the `bug creation page` and it just adds to my irritation. But, yes, the mail-archive clears few things about the mess on Contributor and Author.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha I updated my answer to clear things up..